# Common function for self.errors.add_to_base in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

In my every model i have 10 or more lines for self.errors.add_to_base. is there any other way i can manage those lines in more easy way? will it possible to manage those errors with some common function which can handle self.errors.add_to_base for any of my model?

```
 Function like
 def error_add_to_base(message,conditions)
   self.errors.add_to_base(message) if eval("#{conditions}")
 end
```

Comment: Could you please post some code so we can see what can be done? :]

Comment: Yes, please. From your question it's hard to see what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think that OP asks, if a rails helper method exists, which can be called instead of defining callbacks for each model, where a need for a (custom) validation occurs.
So instead of using 'validate' helper, he would call such helper to report errors that don’t tie to any specific attribute, but to a model instance, "as a whole".

And If I was to answer his question: No, no such "common function" exists. What's wrong with:

```
validate :must_meet_my_business_logic

def :must_meet_my_business_logic
errors.add(:base, "blah!") if...
end
```

anyway?